# $this->getParam() failing to execute in zend1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I used an ajax call to the action index and sendding a parameter as flag:
public/cmm/Controler/index/flag/1
but unable to receive the param using
$fl = $this->getParam('flag');

But this code is working fine in some other part of the page!!

thanks in Advnc

Comment: Where actually are you calling that method?

Comment: its from a view page to the respectd controller's Action (indexAction)

Comment: and what `$this` refers to there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question comments - you're trying to access to it from a view.

If it's the case - then you **shouldn't** do that.

Your view layer should not rely on the request data. So the solution would be:

1. To retrieve it as you always do in a corresponding controller
2. Pass it from a controller from a view

Some draft to demonstrate the idea (in controller):

```
$this->view->flag = $this->getParam('flag');
```

then just use it as

```
$this->flag
```

in a view

Comment: How is passing a parameter as you suggest any better than accessing the request parameter from within? Either way the view relies on the request data. They're just two means of accomplishing the same thing, and the difference is entirely esoteric.

Comment: @Tim Burch: presumably you need to learn something about design patterns first before continuing this discussion. Thank you. PS: "the difference is entirely esoteric" --- it's not. The same view might be used in multiple contexts. In some of them `Zend_Controller_Front` may be not instantiated. IE: CLI applications.

Comment: Clearly you can't explain it.

Comment: @Tim Burch: if it makes you feel better - yep, I cannot explain it.

Comment: Does the question mention multiple contexts? Or does it suggest that Zend_Controller_Front may not be instantiated? You're grasping at straws.

Comment: @Tim Burch: it doesn't, that's why I provided a solution that will work in **every single case** and that follows the best design principles.

Comment: I think you've taken for granted those "design principles" and not really thought about them. Like Zend itself, your solution strikes me as clunky. Good night.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to get a parameter from within a controller is as follows:

```
$fl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('flag');
```

The parameters are attributes of the request rather than the controller itself.

If you're looking to get the parameter from within a view (I can't quite tell), the following code will do so:

```
$fl = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('flag');
```

Comment: There is a `getParam()` method defined in `Zend_Controller_Action` and it does exactly what you proposed. Check the comments - they run it from a *view* - so that's why it fails.

Comment: @zerkms Last I checked, there is no getParam() method in the documentation for Zend_Controller_Action (http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Action.html#_getParam). Perhaps you are confusing it with the _getParam() method? I tested out getParam() within a controller of a Zend application of mine and it throws an exception: Method "getParam" does not exist and was not trapped in __call().

Comment: you probably shouldn't check the 5.5 years old versions next time. The actual (1.12) version: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php#L600

Comment: Clearly I'm using an older version of Zend, and for all you know, so might the OP. Therefore, my solution is more error-proof than yours.

Comment: dude, he is invoking it **IN A VIEW**. Your solution won't work, because **THERE IS NO** `gerRequest()` in a `Zend_View`. Please, hold your breath and start reading carefully. Thank you.

Comment: @zerkms You still have yet to provide a solution yourself, only criticism.

Comment: I prefer to not provide anything when the question lacks important info rather than provide anything that won't work anyway. Do you realize your answer is wrong?

Comment: Do you realize you have no answer?

Comment: I do. Because I prefer not to advice anything over advising a bs. PS: what if there is no `Zend_Controller_Front` instance created?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide solutions for multiple cases, but you can keep it voted down just to pout. Only know, an answer is worth more than a comment and a vote down any day.

Comment: well, there is a good answer - OP **should not** access a request from a View. But, well, it's easier indeed to answer some bs rather than to teach someone how to do it **properly**

Comment: If you really believe that to be the answer, which I doubt given that you haven't supplied an answer, then you ought to offer it up as such. Otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time. Good night, zerkms, who doesn't have an answer.

Comment: well, I provided one. That gives some useful info for the OP to provide a better code. You know what quality code looks like, don't you? PS: well, seems like you have no idea, lol :-D

Comment: I told you what I thought of your answers. Substantively it's no different from mine. But I'm sure you have a made-up reason that's not your own that you'll use to convince yourself it's better.

Comment: it is different. With your proposal - you won't be able to use the same view for Web based and CLI application. Just because you're not following the best design practices, your solution is limited by a very narrow set of cases.

Comment: @All. I think u misunderstand my question. Im new to zend or MVC

Comment: @All. I think u misunderstand my question. Im new to zend or MVC. Here the ajax call from view goes to the server (to the url in the question). In my controller, Action Im trying to get the parameter using getParam(). (I know we can use _getParam() and _request->get() etc.. but the the case is Here Im failing the execution but in the same code works in other Action. I want to know why this happen?

Comment: @TimBurch : I up vote because If you do not specify the second parameter of $this->getParam(), $this->getRequest()->getParam('flag') and $this->getParam('flag') are the same thing. :)